# how to embed if statement for sql cmd export

Tags: sql, csv, export-to-csv

I have a SQL cmd that runs and exports out a CSV file.   How do I compare to fields that are being returned in my query and display text in the export based on those fields?     Where it has the "Title" section I want to compare 2 fields "First_Unit" and "Unit".  If they are equal I want to add text "Primary" if they are not then I want "Backup".    So it is in this section and here is how it would look logically: 'BWC - ' + UPPER(Complaint) + **'Primary' ELSE 'Backup'** as Title.   So the 2 texts I would want to appear at the end of this data in that column.

Thanks
TJ

Here is original query:

```
sqlcmd -S PDCAD -d Ver2_CAD -E -Q "select Active_Calls.Call_Number AS 'Event ID',Officer_IDs AS 'Officer Badge ID', Date_Received AS 'Officer Dispatched DateTime',Time_Complete AS 'Officer Cleared DateTime',Active_Calls.Call_Number AS 'Report Number',UPPER(Complaint) AS 'Category', '' as Tag,'BWC - ' + UPPER(Complaint) as Title,Actual_Incid_Location AS 'Street',Actual_Incid_City AS 'City', ISNULL(Actual_Incid_State,'CT') AS 'State', RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Actual_Incid_ZIP),5) AS 'ZIP Code' from Active_Calls INNER JOIN CALLUNITDATA CALLUNITDATA ON Active_Calls.Call_Number=CALLUNITDATA.Call_Number WHERE Officer_IDs <> 'NHFD' AND Officer_IDs <> 'POST53' AND Officer_IDs <> 'POST54' AND Officer_IDs <> 'POST52'  AND Officer_IDs <> 'DFD' AND Officer_IDs <> 'NFD' AND Officer_IDs <> 'DFD3' AND Officer_IDs <> 'NHFD2' AND Officer_IDs <> 'UNIT50' AND Officer_IDs <> 'NFD2' AND Officer_IDs <> 'DFD2' AND Officer_IDs <> '1129'AND Officer_IDs <> '2120' AND Officer_IDs <> '0341' AND Officer_IDs <> 'MOB.UNIT51' AND Officer_IDs <> '3540' AND Date_Received >= DATEADD(day, -4, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Date_Received" -o "C:\TaserExportFolder\MyData.csv" -h 852544 -s"," -w 700 -W
```

Comment: I was trying to use a CASE statement but it was causing an error in it.

Comment: What did your CASE look like and what was the error?

Comment: The problem was i was not enclosing the CASE statement in () so it was giving a error on processing the query.   I do not remember what the exact error stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CASE statement like so:

```
'BWC - ' + UPPER(Complaint) + (CASE WHEN First_Unit = Unit THEN 'Primary' ELSE 'Secondary' END) As Title
```

See:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/439e14/1

Comment: Glad it helped. :) Do you mind accepting the answer in that case?